# Correlations between variables based on gender in R

Tags: r, regression, correlation

I have a data set in which female is coded as 0 and male as 1 and then I have different testing scores; writing, reading, math. I want to determine whether the correlation between math and writing scores significantly differs between the male and female populations. How would I code this in R? Note: My sample sizes for females is greater than males.

Comment: Essentially you could frame it as a hypothesis, with the null that the there is no interaction between gender and math in predicting writing scores. Then fit the regression E[Writing | Gender, Math] = a + b Writing + c Math + d Writing Math. If the coefficient d is statistically significantly different from 0, you can reject the null.

Comment: The coefficient d can be significantly different from 0 while the correlations are the same. This can happen when the genders do not have the same variance in scores of math or writing.

Answer (score 4):

To show how you could approach this problem with a Monte Carlo simulation (as suggested in Sextus Empiricus's answer)...

You could either do it with a permutation test (AKA randomisation test) or with bootstrapping. I have chosen the latter.

First, I created some fake data that should look somewhat like yours:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

SAMPLE_SIZE <- 1000
MALE_PROP <- 0.4
n_males <- SAMPLE_SIZE * MALE_PROP
n_females <- SAMPLE_SIZE * (1 - MALE_PROP)

males <- data.frame(
  gender = rep(1, n_males),
  writing = rnorm(n = n_males, mean = 60, sd = 10)
) %>% 
  mutate(math = writing * 0.80 + rnorm(n = n_males, mean = 5, sd = 5))

females <- data.frame(
  gender = rep(0, n_females),
  writing = rnorm(n = n_females, mean = 60, sd = 10)
) %>% 
  mutate(math = writing * 0.65 + rnorm(n = n_females, mean = 5, sd = 5))

df <- males %>% 
  bind_rows(females)
```

We have 1,000 individuals, 40% of whom are males. Here is a sample of 5 rows:

| gender | writing | math |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 56.47547 | 46.80284 |
| 1 | 62.11980 | 50.17477 |
| 0 | 65.14230 | 51.73375 |
| 0 | 66.81830 | 55.42685 |
| 1 | 64.26464 | 55.45913 |

And this is what the correlations between writing and math scores look like for the two genders:

```r
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = writing, y = math, colour = factor(gender))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', colour = 'black') +
  facet_wrap(~ gender) +
  labs(colour = 'gender')
```

[image: Raw correlations]

Note that you can calculate the actual sample correlations by doing:

```r
cor(males$writing, males$math)
# [1] 0.8460947
cor(females$writing, females$math)
# [1] 0.8002061
```

so we see that males have a slightly higher correlation. But is this difference statistically significant?

---

Now, here is where the magic happens. We draw 10,000 bootstrap resamples (*with replacement*) for each gender, calculate the respective correlations, and store the differences between male and female correlations:

```r
male_rows <- df %>% 
    filter(gender == 1) %>% 
    select(writing, math)

female_rows <- df %>% 
    filter(gender == 0) %>% 
    select(writing, math)

N_BOOT <- 10000

corr_deltas <- numeric(N_BOOT)

for (i in 1:N_BOOT) {
  male_boot <- male_rows %>% 
    slice_sample(prop = 1, replace = TRUE)
  
  female_boot <- female_rows %>% 
    slice_sample(prop = 1, replace = TRUE)
  
  male_corr <- cor(male_boot$writing, male_boot$math)
  female_corr <- cor(female_boot$writing, female_boot$math)
  
  corr_delta <- male_corr - female_corr
  
  corr_deltas[i] <- corr_delta
}
```

Now we have all we need. We can plot a histogram of the correlation differences together with their 95% confidence interval:

```r
lower_bound_95ci <- quantile(corr_deltas, 0.025)
upper_bound_95ci <- quantile(corr_deltas, 0.975)

ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = corr_deltas)) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = lower_bound_95ci), linetype = 'dashed') +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = upper_bound_95ci), linetype = 'dashed') +
  labs(title = paste(
    'The 95% CI for the difference in correlations is (',
    round(lower_bound_95ci, 3), ',', round(upper_bound_95ci, 3), ')'),
    subtitle = 'Therefore, males have a higher correlation than women.',
    x = 'correlation delta')
```

[image: Bootstrap distribution]

Since the 95% CI does not include 0 in this case, we would conclude that the correlation between writing and math scores was significantly higher for males than for females.

Answer (score 2):

If your population is approximately normal distributed then you can approximate the distribution of a correlation coefficient by a normal distribution after applying a Fisher transformation.

$$z = 0.5 \log \frac{1+r}{1-r} \sim N\left(\mu,\sigma^2\right)$$

where $\mu = 0.5 \log \frac{1+\rho}{1-\rho}$ and $\sigma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N-3}}$ where $\rho$ is the true correlation of the population and $N$ is the sample size.

Then you can take the difference of the two $z$ scores (based on your two correlations) and given the hypothesis that you have the same correlation the difference should be normal distributed with zero mean and standard deviation $\sqrt{\frac{1}{N_1-3}+\frac{1}{N_2-3}}$.

---

If your population is not approximately normal distributed, then you could approximate the distribution with a [Monte Carlo method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) like resampling and observing the variation that occurs among the different samples. This works better if you have a large sample size.